# Counterpart of Chow test for Least absolute deviations (regression analysis)

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing

Does is exist counterpart of Chow test for Least absolute deviations method in analytical or not version ? In least absolute deviations we minimize sum of absolute values of errors.